# I installed Ubuntu today on my E: Local Disk alongside Windows 10.... I created a partition an ext4 partition in E:

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

My local disks C & D and absolutely fine... But can I still access my data from the local disk E:... (And I did not format the disk) The size of the partition was also smaller than the size of the disk. It will be very very very helpful if I can still access that data...